# How do I kick bandwidth-hogging clients on my home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

My family doesn't know how bandwidth works and when I try to explain it to them they really don't seem to care.  Think Netflix during a YouTube video with a concurrent download per person.  This makes it impossible to use Skype or play games.  How do I identify which devices are using the most bandwidth and temporarily kick them from the network?  Can this be done with software or do I need a fancy router?

Comment: What are you using as a means of a router (I.E. Netgear and model like wise to Linksys and or are you using an external router at all)

Comment: Why is your network usage more important than theirs?

Comment: If they have an external router available for use like netgear and or Linksys for an example the person can add and use QoS (Quality Over Service) this only comes in handy for when you have limited bandwidth as these two routers mentioned before I have and used such a service (QoS) on a regular basis as I had 2Mbps of headroom therefore streaming and or downloading something is shared between everyone except if there are more than 4 devices on the same network as then you will have an issue to even stay afloat in this

Comment: I have not needed to use this service at this time but in the past i did, and completely banning them WILL cause conflict and you *WILL* need to configure each device manually as you will only see a list of IP Addresses unless the devices share their device name (Jhon Appleseed's iPod touch) but most don't and the router will say Unknown Device. If you do decide to ban them IT IS AT YOUR OWN RISK and i do agree with the comment by Steven as there is a way around it

Comment: Get your own internet connection ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the-it-guy-you-dont-like, this can be done by putting DDWRT or OpenWRT on your AP and then configure per user QoS so that there is fairness for everyone. You can then create a separate QoS class for yourself and allocate better bandwidth for yourself ;)

Having said that, installing OpenWRT and DDWRT does run a risk of bricking your AP, so check out the supported device list read about your AP's support in detail and then go for it. If nothing works buy a $20 AP like TP Link 740(or 841), that will work very well with OpenWRT.

OpenWRT supported hardware list is here http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

DDWRT supported hardware list is here http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices

Personally I find OpenWRT to be better than DDWRT but DDWRT's configuration interface is more user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

To measure all the data flowing in and out of your home network, you’d need to measure the data usage on your home router itself.

Sadly, regular home routers don't come with this feature built-in but you can install third party router firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)

Comment: There are some routers that will end up bricking if you were to add and or use 3rd party firmware let alone flashing it correctly in turn there is a marginal risk involved in this method